# Display results of two queries in view using asp.net MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have this code that works.

```
public class HelloWorldController : Controller
{
    UAStagingEntities db = new UAStagingEntities();

    public ActionResult Index(int? id)
    {
        var depot = db.CSLA_DEPOT.Where(c => c.DEPOT_ID == id.Value);

        return View(depot.ToList());
     }

}
```

What I don't know how to do is display a view with results from two queries.  How would I create the view to show both depot and address?  and how would I code the return statement?

```
public class HelloWorldController : Controller
{
    UAStagingEntities db = new UAStagingEntities();

    public ActionResult Index(int? id)
    {
         var depot = db.CSLA_DEPOT.Where(c => c.DEPOT_ID == id.Value);
         var Address = db.CSLA_ADDRESS.Where(a => a.CSLA_DEPOT.DEPOT_ID == id.Value);

         return View(depot.ToList());
    }
}
```

EDIT *

I added this model

```
    namespace CustomerCareMVC.Models
{
    public class CSLA_StagingModel

    {

        public List<CSLA_DEPOT> depots { get; set; }
        public List<CSLA_ADDRESS> addresses { get; set; }

    }

}
```

And added this method in the controller

```
    public ActionResult ShowAllTables() 
    {


        var model = new CSLA_StagingModel()
        {

            depots = db.CSLA_DEPOT.Where(c => c.DEPOT_ID == 10065),
            addresses = db.CSLA_ADDRESS.Where(a => a.CSLA_DEPOT.DEPOT_ID == 10065),
        };


        return View(model);

    }
```

I get squiggly line under these two lines

```
            depots = db.CSLA_DEPOT.Where(c => c.DEPOT_ID == 10065),
            addresses = db.CSLA_ADDRESS.Where(a => a.CSLA_DEPOT.DEPOT_ID == 10065),
```

with this error message

Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) C:\CustCareMVC\CustomerCareMVC\CustomerCareMVC\Controllers\HelloWorldController.cs  59  26  CustomerCareMVC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to create a ViewModel that has the following paramters:

```
public IQueryable<CSLA_DEPOT> depots {get; set;}
public IQueryable<CSLA_ADDRESS> addresses {get; set;}
```

You would then need to create an instance of this new View Model in your controller like so:

```
var model = new ViewModelName(){
    depots = db.CSLA_DEPOT.Where(c => c.DEPOT_ID == id.Value),
    addresses = db.CSLA_ADDRESS.Where(a => a.CSLA_DEPOT.DEPOT_ID == id.Value),
};
```

You would then need to pass this model to your view like so:

```
return View(model);
```

In your view you would access the two different collections like so:

```
Model.depots
Model.addresses
```

Hope this helps, leave me a comment if you have any questions.

Comment: DevDave, I'm trying to implement this code and I'm getting an error.  Added it to the question under the work EDIT.  thanks

Comment: Joshua, I had a bug in my code.  Please note that the model is now referencing IQueryable for each variable instead of list.  This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create a special object that contains two items of the types returned by your queries. Then you can access them with Model.depot and Model.Address in your View.

Comment: do you not know the types returned by the queries?

Comment: No i don't.  I'm querying tables and filtering they by the id number which is entered by the user on the webpage.

Comment: in your models folder. you could create a class that contains two fields. one for each list. i think you could use the types created by Entity Framework. then for the strongly typed view, select the class created with the two lists.